# the continuation theorem and Sobolev spaces

Tags: lebesgue-measure, sobolev-spaces

I know the continuation theorem: let $Q, \Omega$ are limited domain, $\delta Q \in C^k,~ \overline{Q} \subset \Omega $, $f(x) \in H^k(Q)$. Then there is a function $F(x) \in H^k(\Omega)$ is finitnaya in $\Omega$, such that $F(x) = f(x), ~ x \in Q $. More over there is a constant $M$ that does not depend on $f(x)$ such that $\|F(x)\|_{H^k(\Omega)} \leq M \|f(x)\|_{H^k(Q)} $. My question is can we quantify  $\|F(x)\|_{L_2(\Omega)}$ like there is a constant $M^*$ that does not depend on $f(x)$ such that $\|F(x)\|_{L_2(\Omega)} \leq \|f(x)\|_{L_2(Q)}$ ?

Comment: Look at Stein’s book, Singular Integrals and Differentiability Properties of Functions

Comment: @Deane, Can you indicate chapter number and 
paragraph number , please?

Comment: Sorry. I don’t have access to the book right now. There’s a whole section about extension operators.